# Set attribute for custom DOM nodes in text preview component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add / setAttribute class for custom DOM nodes while writing some text in custom `bbcode`-like text editor. When the `innerHTML` of `<item></item>` is not empty I'm filtering through `items` array in order to find the value that matches. *There can be unlimited amount of `item` nodes. (i.e 2, 5, 10)*

So whenever i click on icon named `item` it shows in textarea as `[item][/item]` and in preview component as `<item></item>`. Once the item is written, lets say `[item]id123[/item]` I have in DOM `<item>itemName123</item>`.

Now, what I'm doing is manipulating the DOM outside React with:

```
const setAttributes = (el, item) =>{
    el.dataset.img = item.img;
    el.setAttribute('class', _.toLower(item.color))
  };

const updateItems = () =>{
    if(document.querySelectorAll('item')) {
      document.querySelectorAll('item').forEach(el => items.find(item => {
        if(_.toLower(el.innerHTML) === _.toLower(item.id))
          setAttributes(el, item)
      }));
    }
 }
```

The problem is, whenever I change the text, component re-renders so that removes attributes that have been set.

I tried to manipulate the text/string before it goes to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` markup by splitting it, going through `includes` with `map`, `filter` all that godsent functions with some regex sauce from ES6 but it just smells bad.

It feels so hacky that i believe that there has to be something that I'm missing.

Edit: Forgot to add that I've also tried to put `setAttributes() &&  updateItems()` outside of class.

Edit#2: The way i'm changing from `[item][/item]` is via regexp `text.replace(/\[item]/g, <item>).replace(/\[\/item]/g, </item>)`, so probably i could do something with regexp instead of `setAtrribute` on each re-render?And if so, i've been trying that via

`new RegExp(/\[item]/+ _.toLower(item.name)+ /\[\/item]/, 'g')`;

and later on `text.replace(<item class="${item.quality}">${_.toLower(item.name)}</item>)`

but no success so far.

Thanks in advance for any tips and ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Used RegExp + `pattern.exec(text)` and looping through text with `while` and replacing any matched occurances. Then used `for(let..of)` loop to compare the matched values and overwrite the value.